# Cauchy problem and solution saturated

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $T>0$, let $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lipschitz function with $$f(t,x)=f(t+T,x), \quad \forall (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$$
Prove that por each $(t_{0},x_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ the saturated solution $x(t;t_{0},x_{0})$ of the Cauchy problem $$x'=f(t,x), \quad \forall x(t_{0})=x_{0}$$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $$x(t;t_{0},x_{0})=x(t+T,t_{0}+T,x_{0}), \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

I know that a solution that is not extensible is called saturated. In other words, a solution $ \phi $ defined on an interval $ I $ is saturated if $ I $ is its maximal domain of existence.

Comment: Do you know [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem?wprov=sfti1) and the *associated length* of the maximal solutions?

Comment: yes, I know that theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the global version of Cauchy Lipschitz theorem (see II.4.1 in [this paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eadrien.deloro/teaching-archive/AIMS/ODEs.pdf)), the IVP problem of the question has a unique and global solution for each $(t_0,x_0) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n$.

Also
$$x^\prime(t+T;t_{0}+T,x_{0}) = f(t+T, x(t+T;t_{0}+T,x_{0})) = f(t, x(t+T;t_{0}+T,x_{0}))$$ and $x(t_0+T;t_{0}+T,x_{0})=x_0$. Which means that $x(t+T;t_{0}+T,x_{0})$ and $x(t;t_0,x_0)$ are both solution of the same IVP problem. By unicity those two maps are equal.